# Как манипулировать данными внутри инпута?

Tags: css

В моём конкретном случае нужно добавить появляющемуся тексту отступы слева (или центрировать, ...). 
Я думал, нужно задавать свойства с использованием атрибута, что-то типа этого, но что-то не работает:

```
input [value='']{
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно в чем проблема. Все работает

```css
.left {
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 90px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input class="left" value="Left" /><br />
<input class="center" value="Center" />
```

Comment: Решение нашёл в другом месте

Comment: Так опубликуйте его. Но смысл вопроса я так и не понял

Answer (score 0):

можно при помощи :valid , но необходимо, чтобы у input стоял required,

```
input:valid{
    padding-left: var(--input_padding--left);
}
```

еще можно при помощи следующих псевдоклассов, но пока работает токлько на webkite (хром)

```
input:-webkit-autofill{
    padding-left: var(--input_padding--left);
}

input:placeholder-shown{
    padding-left: var(--input_padding--left);
}

input:placeholder-shown + .input__placeholder{
    padding-left: var(--input_padding--left);
}
```